# grab variable from page and store in new variable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to grab dynamic data as below. Seen from file.

```
<tr>
    <td><%= locationNumber %></td>
    <td><%= locationDba %></td>
    <td><%= address1 %><%= address2 %><br><%= city %>, <%= state %> <%= zipcode %></td>
    <td><%= storePhone%></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to write javascript in a global js file that grabs 'locationDba' variable or dynamic content and stores in a new variable that I create so I can use it across an application easier with a new variable; EG. newlocationDBA. But with the same data as found working in original file 'locationDba'.

```
    <td><%= **new**locationDba %></td>
```

**Alright! Update; below is my most recent attempt with no results.**

---

Mark-Up. CALL.

```
   <option><%= myGlobalDba %></option>
```

JS file.

```
var myGlobalDba = document.getElementById('search').innerHTML;
```

Mark-Up. GRAB.

```
<td id="search"><%= locationDba %></td>
```

So, shouldnt my mark-up call output the exact same as  original <%= locationDba %>
? Am I missing something within the javaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td id='cows'><%= **new**locationDba %></td>
```

and

```
var myGlobalDba = document.getElementById('cows').innerHTML;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then you are missing something about your question. For example, what is `<%= **new**locationDba %>`? Looks like a server-side template.

Comment: Excellent answer! Though for some reason I am still outputting as dead.

Comment: Well the original dynamic content is coming from the 'Mark-up CALL' - in which I would like to grab this dynamic content > and shoot it into my new variable that I would be using in > <option> tag because it is to populate within a drop-down bar.